# Block data are not shown in PHML magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, phtml

I am new to **Magento 2** module development.

I have a custom table `sample_data(id,sample_text,sample_number)`

I want to fetch a listing of this custom table.But unfortunately when I type `www.magentolocalhost.dev/sample/sample/sampledata`,
I am getting a blank page.

```
Controller
---------------->Sample
                    -->SampleData.php
Model
--------ResourceModel
    --------------SampleData
                        Collection.php
        SampleData.php
Sampledata.php
Block
Sampledata.php
view
-------->frontend
        ----->layout
                sample_sample_sampledata.xml
        ----->templates
                Samplelist.php
```

**SampleData.php (Action)**

```
namespace Packt\SampleData\Controller\Sample;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
class SampleData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context,PageFactory $pageFactory) 
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() 
    {

       return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Sampledata.php(model)**

```
namespace Packt\SampleData\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
class Sampledata extends AbstractModel implements IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'Packt_SampleData';
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init("\Packt\SampleData\Model\ResourceModel\Sampledata");
    }
    public function getIdentities() {
         return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }
}
```

**ResourceModel\SampleData.php(ResourceModel)**

```
namespace Packt\SampleData\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Sampledata extends AbstractDb
{
 public function _construct() 
    {
     $this->_init("sample_data", "id");
    }   
    public function getSampleTextById($id)
    {
        $adapter =  $this->getConnection();
        $select =$adapter->select()->from($this->getMainTable(), "sample_text")->where("id=:id");
        $binds = ["id"=>(int)$id];
        return $adapter->fetchOne($select, $binds);
    }
}
```

**ResourceModel\Sampledata\Collection.php(Collection)**

```
namespace Packt\SampleData\Model\ResourceModel\Sampledata;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    public function _construct() 
    {
        $this->_init("Packt\SampleData\Model\Sampledata", "Packt\SampleData\Model\ResourceModel\Sampledata");
    }

}
```

**Block**

```
namespace Packt\SampleData\Block;
class Sampledata extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_SampledataFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Packt\SampleData\Model\SampledataFactory $SampledataFactory, array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_SampledataFactory = $SampledataFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }
    public function _prepareLayout() 
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->_SampledataFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }

}
```

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Packt\SampleData\Block\Sampledata" name="Packt_SampleData" template="Packt_SampleData::Samplelist.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**Samplelist.phtml(Template)**

```
<?php var_dump($block->getCollection())?>
```

Comment: Have you tried with custom function from block with return type string ?

Comment: Yes I have called a custom function with return type string it is working.

Comment: Check it out, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104053/magento-2-print-r-or-var-dump-is-not-working this will help you to understand

Comment: Great link I have two problem one is layout xml file name and another is print_r /var_dump does not work on phtml. thanks